# How to convert long data format to wide data format in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, formatting

I have data in the long format and would like to convert as wide format with sparse data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1000,1001,1000,1002,1003,1000],
                   'Date':[26018,26017,26016,26010,26009,26009]})
```

[image: input data]

And it is to be converted as wide format by assigning ones:

[image: output data]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Idea is add helper column and pivoting by [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), add missing values by [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) and last convert misisng values to `0` with casting to integers:

```
df1 = (df.assign(new = 1)
         .pivot('id','Date','new')
         .reindex(range(df['Date'].min(), df['Date'].max() + 1), axis=1)
         .fillna(0)
         .astype(int))
print (df1)
Date  26009  26010  26011  26012  26013  26014  26015  26016  26017  26018
id                                                                        
1000      1      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      0      1
1001      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      0
1002      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
1003      1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
```

If get:

> ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

it means there are duplicates like in last row of changed sample data. Then add [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1000,1001,1000,1002,1003,1000, 1000],
                   'Date':[26018,26017,26016,26010,26009,26009, 26009]})


df1 = (df.assign(new = 1)
         .drop_duplicates(subset=['id','Date'])
         .pivot('id','Date','new')
         .reindex(range(df['Date'].min(), df['Date'].max() + 1), axis=1)
         .fillna(0)
         .astype(int))
print (df1)
Date  26009  26010  26011  26012  26013  26014  26015  26016  26017  26018
id                                                                        
1000      1      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      0      1
1001      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      0
1002      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
1003      1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
```

Notice: My solution not counts rows, only return `1` if exist intersection `id` and `Date` else `0`.

Comment: instead of pivot(), if we use pivot_table() the duplicates are ignored and its working fine. not sure why !!

Comment: @Mrutyunjaya - If there are duplicates then it count `means` and if means of all `1` values get `1`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `crosstab` in case you are counting the frequency also

```
df1 = pd.crosstab(df['id'], df['Date']).reindex(range(df['Date'].min(), df['Date'].max() + 1), axis=1).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

**Output of df1:**

```
Date  26009  26010  26011  26012  26013  26014  26015  26016  26017  26018
id                                                                        
1000      1      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      0      1
1001      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      0
1002      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
1003      1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
```

Answer (score 1):

You may take advantage of `groupby.size` and `unstack`. Finally, `reindex` as other solutions

```
ix = range(df.Date.min(), df.Date.max()+1)
df_final = (df.groupby(['id', 'Date']).size()
              .unstack(fill_value=0)
              .reindex(ix, axis=1, fill_value=0))

Out[205]:
Date  26009  26010  26011  26012  26013  26014  26015  26016  26017  26018
id
1000      1      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      0      1
1001      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      0
1002      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
1003      1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
```